# ionic 2 + angular 2 : auto scroll to bottom of list / page / chat

Tags: javascript, angular, chat, ionic2, autoscroll

I'm trying to code a page with two segments "chat" and "content". I want that one "chat" segment the page auto-scroll to the bottom with no effect. The chat is a `<ion-list>` with several `<ion-item>`.

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item> item 1 </ion-item>
<ion-item> item 2 </ion-item>
....
<ion-item> item 20 </ion-item>
<ion-item> item 21 </ion-item> <!-- user should see directly this item on bottom of the page -->
</ion-list>
```

I'm using Javascript, not typescript, and I don't wan't to use jQuery.
Thanks :)
Plus, when I go to "content" segment and go back to "chat" I want to auto-scroll again the chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off all, @rinukkusu answer is right but it doesn't work on my case because `<ion-content>` (parent of `<ion-list>`) has some bugs with it (ionic developers are working on that), so I had to put that element with `scroll:hidden` and create a second content inside to apply the auto-scroll.
Finally with the right (s)css I called the function on `construtor` when the page loads and then each time the users clicks on "chat" segment.

**chat.html**

```
<!-- I create the segment and call the `autoScroll()` when users clicks on "chat" -->
<ion-toolbar primary class="toolbar-segment">
    <ion-segment light [(ngModel)]="segment">
        <ion-segment-button value="chat" (click)="autoScroll()">
            Chat
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="profile">
            Profile
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>

<!--I wrote the css inline just as example. 
  DON'T do it on your project D: -->

<!-- overflow:hidden prevent the ion-content to scroll -->
<ion-content [ngSwitch]="segment" style="overflow: hidden;">

    <!-- height: 100% to force scroll if the content overflows the container.
         #chat-autoscroll is used by javascript.-->
    <div class="content-scroll" id="chat-autoscroll" *ngSwitchWhen="'chat'" style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
        (... make sure the content is bigger 
        than the container to see the auto scroll effect ...)
    </div>

    <!-- here it's just a normal scroll  -->
    <div *ngSwitchWhen="'profile'" class="content-scroll" style="height: 100%; overflow: auto">
      (... content of profile segment ...)
    </div>

</ion-content>
```

**chat.js**

```
constructor () {

    // when the user opens the page, it shows the "chat" segment as initial value
    this.segment = 'chat'; 

    // when page loads, it calls autoScroll();
    if (this.segment == 'chat') {
        console.log('chat');
        this.autoScroll();
    };
}

/*Here comes the tricky. 
 If you don't use setTimeout, the console will say that
 #chat-autoscroll doesn't exist in the first call (inside constructor). 
 This happens because the script runs before the DOM is ready. 
 I did a workaround with a timeOut of 10ms.
 It's enough time to DOM loads and then autoScroll() works fine.
*/
autoScroll() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var itemList = document.getElementById("chat-autoscroll");
        itemList.scrollTop = itemList.scrollHeight;
    }, 10);
}
```

**Conclusion:**
The function is called twice. When the page is loaded (constructor) and each time the user comes back to "chat" segment. (click)="autoScroll()"

I hope this helps someone. If you know better way, let me know! I started playing with Angular2 and Ionic2 a couple of weeks ago so there is a lot of concepts/bases that I might be missing here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 32):

Here's how I did it:

**chatPage.html**

```
<ion-content #content padding class="chatPage">

  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages" >
      <chat-bubble [message]="msg"></chat-bubble>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

The important bit in **chatPage.html** is `#content` on `<ion-content>`. I'll use the `#content` identifier to obtain a reference to `<ion-content>` in my **chatPage.js** using the `ViewChild`.

Now for the actual scrolling logic:

**chatPage.js**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/chatPage/chatPage.html',
  queries: {
    content: new ViewChild('content')
  }
})
export class ChatPage {
  constructor() { 

  }

  //scrolls to bottom whenever the page has loaded
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);//300ms animation speed
  }
}
```

Also, whenever my **chatPage** needs to show another chat message in the list (either a new message is received, or a new message is sent), I'm using the below code to scroll to the new bottom:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.content.scrollToBottom(300);//300ms animation speed
});
```

---

**Update for Typescript**

Back when I gave this answer I was working with JavaScript version of Ionic 2 project. Over time I switched to TypeScript but I forgot to update the answer, so, here's a small update for **chatPage.js(ts)**:

**chatPage.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'chatPage.html'
})
export class ChatPage {
  @ViewChild('content') content:any;

  constructor() { }

  //scrolls to bottom whenever the page has loaded
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);//300ms animation speed
  }
}
```

Comment: does the timeout fix the delay of the ngFor being updated ? Because without the timeout it scrolls to bottom but adds the new row after scrolling

Comment: @Ismail That's right. That's why added the timeout.

Comment: `this.content` is undefined.

Comment: @smukov i followed your steps but getting scrollbottom of **null**

Comment: For those who still received `undefined` in `this.content`. Try adding the following:

1) In the template, add `#content` to the ion-content tag. Example: `<ion-content #content>`

2) In the controller, add the `Content` import, example: `import { Content } from "ion-angular";`

and modify the `content` declaration as follows: `@ViewChild (Content) private content: Content;`. Hope this help someone.

Comment: @smukov Is there any method as `this.content.scrollToTop(300);`

Answer (score 18):

The Ionic has an option to do this and works pretty good: And this is the most appropriate way with angular 2+ and Ionic.

```
import { Content } from ‘ionic-angular’;

export class CommentsPage{
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    ionViewWillEnter(): void {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    scrollToBottom() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.content.scrollToBottom();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: An ionic solution instead of an angular one, deserves more upvotes

Comment: How would you call this method when a new message is or content is added to the current page. I can scroll to the bottom on ionViewWillEnter but the app stops if I call it when a content is added.

Comment: @fanbondi What are you talking about, just call the scroll to bottom when the data is added

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to "observe" changes in the scroll view and scroll automatically.
i.e. if there are new HTML elements where the messages appear then scroll to the bottom.

```
export class MessagesPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  autoScroller: MutationObserver;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.autoScroller = this.autoScroll();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.autoScroller.disconnect();
  }

  autoScroll(): MutationObserver {
    const autoScroller = new MutationObserver(this.scrollDown.bind(this));

    autoScroller.observe(this.messagesList, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

    return autoScroller;
  }

  scrollDown(): void {
    this.scroller.scrollTop = this.scroller.scrollHeight;
    this.messageEditor.focus();
  }

  private get messageEditor(): HTMLInputElement {
    return <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('ion-input');
  }

  private get messagesList(): Element {
    return document.querySelector('.messages');
  }

  private get scroller(): Element {
    return this.messagesList.querySelector('.scroll-content');
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">
    <ion-list>
      <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
        <p [innerHtml]="message.text"></p>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="message" type="text" placeholder="Write a message..." autocomplete="true" spellcheck="true" tappable></ion-input>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="sendMessage()">
        <ion-icon name="paper-plane"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

(take from [Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp on Github](https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp/blob/42127655c99c68f2cbda04c7f418fd58353b9b3e/src/pages/messages/messages.ts))

Answer (score 2):

This could help someone, I have given similar answer [in Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-scroll-bottom/45041/17). This is implemented in Ionic 3.

I used `ngAfterViewChecked()` to achieve this feature. Following is my code structure -

**home.html -**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div #scrollMe id="messages-container" style="overflow: auto; height: 100%;">
        // All messages elemets. Scroll
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts -**

```
import { Component,ViewChild, AfterViewChecked, * * } from '@angular/core';
.
.
export class HomePage implements AfterViewChecked{
    // used for scrolling the pane
    @ViewChild('scrollMe') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

    scrollToBottom(): void {
        // method used to enable scrolling
        this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    }
}
```

`.scrollTop` and `.scrollHeight` are JavaScript properties, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight).

Answer (score 1):

I added a check to see if the user tried to scroll up.

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; height: xyz;" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
    <div class="..." 
        *ngFor="..."
        ...>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with Ionic CLI 5.4.16 :

In page HTML:

```
<ion-content #content>
```

In page .TS:

```
@ViewChild('content', { static: true }) content: any;



 constructor(){}

  getInformation(){

//Your Code 

..........

//At the end

  **this.content.scrollToBottom();**

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just do it:

```
public ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This should work if your `ion-list` element has a fixed height.

```
<ion-list id="item-list">
    <ion-item> item 1 </ion-item>
    <ion-item> item 2 </ion-item>
    [...]
    <ion-item> item 20 </ion-item>
    <ion-item> item 21 </ion-item>
</ion-list>

[...]

<script>
    var itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");
    itemList.scrollTop = itemList.scrollHeight
</script>
```

Comment: sorry but nothing happens :/

Comment: Could you share a little more code? Like is that a template or where do you expect the javascript to scroll down?

Comment: hey, sorry it works on codepen, the problem here is that i'm using flexbox, so it isn't working with it. ill try a little more and give up feedback in minutes.