# Dynamically scrolling to bottom of list with scrollbars

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a list of people that I am looping through. Each person has their own `ion-item`. The list has scrollbars so I can scroll up and down and see all the people.

Using typescript, how can I scroll to the bottom of the list? When the page loads I see the people from the top but would like to call a function that jumps me to the bottom of the list.

```
<ion-slide class="add-scrollbars">          
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let p of gameData?.points">
        <h2><strong>{{ p.name }}</strong></h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list> 
</ion-slide>
```

My CSS to add the scrollbars ...

```
.add-scrollbars {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

My list is being updated constantly and I want to have a function that I can call when there's an update that will jump me to the bottom of the list .... but quite often I will have scrolled up and currently don't see new entries being added to the bottom

Comment: You may wish to add tags other than `typescript` to get more eyes on the question. For instance, `ionic` is the framework that uses the `ion` prefix, if I'm not mistaken. Also, this appears to be `angular`.

Comment: Just curious: you don't want to reverse the order of the list instead of scrolling automatically to the end?

Comment: Unfortunately not. My list is being updated constantly and I want to have a function that I can call when there's an update that will jump me to the bottom of the list .... but quite often I will have scrolled up and currently don't see new entries being added to the bottom

Comment: I saw in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37415085/1009922) that some ionic components have a `scrollToBottom` method. Did you try calling that on the `ion-slide` element?